# Does there exist a homomorphism of commutative rings with unit from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3)$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does there exist a homomorphism of commutative rings with unit from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3)$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$? Either exhibit such a homomorphism, or prove that none exists.

The solution claims "The question amounts to whether $−3$ has a square root in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$". Why?

Comment: If $\alpha\in \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ satisfies $\alpha^2+3=0$ then you can define the homomorphism by sending $x\in \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+3)$ to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ with $\bar x$ mapping to $\sqrt{3}$, and similarly $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - x + 1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+ \sqrt{3}}{2}]$, with $x \mapsto ...$ . Now, there is a natural map ( inclusion ) that maps $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}] $ to $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1+ \sqrt{3}}{2}]$. Now one sorts out that $\bar x$ of the first ring has to go to $\overline{2x -1}$ of the second ring.